# Jenkins on docker won't run on port 8080

Tags: docker, jenkins, windows-10

I have 'docker desktop' installed on my windows 10.

so, I pulled in Jenkins image from docker hub and then run the commands:

```
docker pull jenkins/jenkins

docker volume create jenkins_home

docker run --name jenkins -p 8080:8000 -p 50000:50000 -v C:/Users/myusername/Documents/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins
```

On console, everything was ok, and get the password for the admin user.
So after that I run

```
docker start jenkins
```

and then

```
docker ps -a 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                                        NAMES   
36683f39dd31        jenkins/jenkins                              "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   6 minutes ago          Up 2 minutes              8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8000/tcp   jenkins
```

Now, I need to log into http://localhost:8080/ port to view the Jenkins web app. But did not bring up Jenkins app. I also tried using docker inspect to get the container's ip, but port 8080 didn't work on those ips as well.

```
"NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "19504b4695ca4dfc9c4af41c9a7ef90115004af07d0099ffed33f4838155cddb",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "50000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "50000"
                }
            ],
            "8000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ],
            "8080/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/19504b4695ca",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "f1938dad37524b58d3146f8bfffa4964687d1946ab97b3ae7f0105ced3f64ddf",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "b285258a51bc4877fa9ff8a1928eced061f61a4f92f54a5aa756a118e0f1cb7b",
                "EndpointID": "f1938dad37524b58d3146f8bfffa4964687d1946ab97b3ae7f0105ced3f64ddf",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
```

**NOTE**: Before running jenkins, I made sure the port wasn't busy.

```
netstat -aon | findstr 8080
```

After kenkins running, the command shows me

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       25076
TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       25076
```

If I find the process to use this port, I got this

```
tasklist | findstr 25076
com.docker.backend.exe       25076 Console                    2     22.664 K
```

so, Which ip address do I use to see the Jenkins app that is running in the container? and why the localhost on port 8080 doen't work ?

Comment: You are mapping host port 8080 to container port 8000, whereas Jenkins uses 8080, so change to `-p 8080:8080` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, sometimes the newbies questions are not well received, I am starting with docker. The question may be silly to many, but without a doubt, your answer helped me more than a -1. Thank you.

Comment: @Morfic ok, I deleted my comment. BTW, your comment is a good answer, you should post it as one!

Comment: @ModusTollens That was not my intention, i was not being sarcastic or anything. I apologize if I left that impression and your comment was educative and more than welcome, so I would've loved to still have it. I'm merely here help and get help when required, but I feel sometimes we take things for if granted, like up/down voting instead of spending 30 more seconds to also add a comment which is helpful, so I had to say it. Feel free to add a response if you have the time, I will try to add a more detailed one when I get the chance